# Setting a cookie to remember if chat box is open or closed

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am adding a chat feature to every page of a PHPBB site.  I need the chat bar to be consistently open or closed throughout the users session, as well as when they return.

Here's an example of the chat bar.
http://tennesseeclassictruckclub.com/forum/yshout/slide.html

I think I need to set a cookie that will remember the users preference.  Not familiar with cookies, so I need a little guidance.

1)  Javascript/Jquery code to set the cookie and state of chat bar ("1" for open "0" for closed is fine).

2)  Example of how to read the cookie.

Will this cookie interfere with any cookie's PHPBB sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to use http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie and as long as you name your cookies uniquely enough, no worries about interference.

More detail here:  http://webhole.net/2010/07/10/jquery-cookies-example/